# What does はなはなはな mean in the Okinawan dialect?

Tags: expressions, dialects

What does はなはなはな mean? People were clapping and the expression was used after the karaoke song was completed. This term was used as more of a chant after the person finished singing. This expression was heard while chatting with people from Okinawa.

Comment: Hanahana (華々) しい actually means splendid, beautiful!

Comment: ^ 華々しい is read 「はな**ば**なしい」.

Comment: I mistakenly heard it as hanahana originally.

Comment: @l'électeur told me 「はなはな」(or「はなはなはなはな...」) is Okinawan language. You heard it in Okinawa, Jack?

Comment: Yes the word was used in chatting with an Okinawan.

Comment: @Chocolate, I modified my question to reflect Okinawa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はなはなはな or はなはな are like “cheers!” They’re used before starting to drink.

Comment: I believe the word is cheers!

Comment: You are right. Thanks.